# Selection Sort with Comparators

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, sequence, comparator

I'm very very stuck.  My code runs and sorts something but I can't make it actually sort properly. I've gone through it so many times and I can't seem to figure out why it won't actually sort as it is supposed to:
My comparators should return either -1, 0 or 1:

```
class SortByName implements Comparator<Student> {
   public int compare(Student student, Student otherStudent) {
       return student.getName().compareTo(otherStudent.getName());
   }
}

class SortByRoll implements Comparator<Student> { 
   public int compare(Student student, Student otherStudent) {
       if (student.getRollno() < otherStudent.getRollno()) {
           return -1;
       }
       if (student.getRollno() == otherStudent.getRollno()) {
           return 0;
       }
       else {
           return 1;
       }
   }
}
```

and my selection sort I can't see what would be wrong with it.

```
class SelectionSort {
   public static void sort(
       ArrayList<Student> studentList,
       Comparator<Student> comparator
   ) {
       for (int i = 0; i < studentList.size()-1; ++i) {
           int currentMinIndex = i;
           for (int j = i + 1; j < studentList.size(); ++j) {
               if (
                   comparator.compare(
                       studentList.get(j),
                       studentList.get(currentMinIndex)
                   ) < 0
               ) {
                   currentMinIndex = j;
                   if (currentMinIndex != i) { //If currentMinIndex isn't the last item to be sorted
                       //Swap!
                       Collections.swap(
                           studentList,
                           i,
                           currentMinIndex
                       );
                   }               
               }
           }
       }
   }   
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Since we immediately swap, the `currentMinIndex` should always be `i`. This makes variable `currentMinIndex` superfluous. This, in return, makes the inner `if` superfluous, and we should swap indices `i` and `j` instead of `i` and `currentMinIndex` ([Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/Aa3Ylv)).

Comment: Another (more common) approach would be to swap at most once per outer loop iteration. I will leave this as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer and it is a classic case of something so small.. Thought it took way to long to figure out.
The if and second for statements needed to be closed before the swap. That was it.